# is there a way to get a random line from a file that has a size greater than 0 bytes?

Tags: python

Hopefully you people can help me with that because im completely lost..

I tried many different codes but none of them worked

is there a way to get a random line from a file that has a size greater than 0 bytes?

i want to get a random line from a variable file (name will be based on the user input) and print it to the screen

the conditions are that the file must be more than zero bytes (meaning that it has lines to begin with)

if the file does not exist i want it to be created

the below code doesnt work at all, gives me a second input and while i enter it the program crashes

```
with open(tokens + '.txt') as f:
        if os.path.getsize(tokens + '.txt'):
            lines = f.readlines()
            print(random.choice(lines))
        elif os.stat(f).st_size > 0:
            with open(tokens + '.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                    the_file.write(user_input)
                    the_file.write('\n')
                    the_file.close()
```

Comment: Please share what exactly you have tried so far and what errors you had. Please don't ask people to write a program/code for you given specific requirements.

Comment: ok thank you for the specifying, i will add my sample code now.

Comment: I am very new to this, about 3 days so there are a lost of mistakes....

Comment: When "the program crashes" do you get any error? If yes, please, add it to the question.